# Null pointer exception while using the setCenter method of a MapController in Android

Tags: java, android, android-maps

I'm using this code to set the center of the map.

```
mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6), (int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6)));
```

where location is defined as

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

I get a null pointer exception with this code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The mapController.setCenter line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

You are probably getting a null response from locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29